# How to retrieve one-to-many relationships with Parse.Query

Tags: parse-platform

The [parse documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#relational-queries) explains how to retrieve a parent object when querying for children:

```js
const query = new Parse.Query(Comment);

// Include the post data with each comment
query.include("post");

const comments = await query.find();
```

But it says nothing about going in the other direction (the natural direction, it seems to me): I want to query for posts, and I want each post to include its array of comments. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve one post and all related comments in a single query unless you use [aggregate](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#aggregate).

Without using aggregate, you will have to perform two queries:

```
const post = await (new Parse.Query(Post)).get(postId);
const comments = await (new Parse.Query(Comment)).equalTo('post', post).find();
```

Comment: Right, that's if I'm looking for one post. What if I want to retrieve a set of posts (all posts by a particular user this week, for example), and have each post populated with its comments? Do I have to query for all the posts, then all the comments matching any of those posts, and then collate the results myself? Or is there a way to do it in one step with aggregate?

Comment: You can either use aggregate and return the whole data with a single query or use two queries: one to return all posts at once, and another to return all comments of all posts at once.